# Duplicate .class files after refactoring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netbeans, tomcat8

After moving class from one package (I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2) to another I encountered because of duplicates of one class in two packages. For example after I had moved class to another package (for example from `a.b` to `a.b.c`) and then built my application I have two exactly the same classes but in different catalogs (`a/b/foo.class` and `a/b/c/foo.class`) in `target/snapshot/WEB-INF/classes`.

It was manageable problem when it was happening for one class - I'd just remove redundant one and everything worked fine but since then I've moved few other classes and that solution is just too troublemaking.

That causes problems particularly when Spring going through configuration files and encounter duplicates. In other cases it's just making harmless mess.

For example: I have a `SecurityInitializer` that extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` which previously was part of `web.configuration` package and now it's been moved to `configuration` package and application built creates two .class files - one in folder `target\EShopper-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\eshopper\configuration` as it should and the other in `target\EShopper-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes\eshopper\web\configuration` (which was valid before moving class) which causes problem as there is duplicate of `springSecurityFilterChain`.

Is there a way to prevent from this duplicates?

Comment: Do you `clean`  your project before `build`?

Comment: Yes, I always use clean and build.

Comment: My guess is that you are copying instead of moving the class between packages.  Instead of dragging or using the control keys  you might want to explicitly use the menu Refactor -> Move .